# Mongoose - empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The callback function prints an empty array even if there are two animals with type **dog**. What am I doing wrong? Thanks :)
The node js app looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', { useNewUrlParser: true });

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'an error occured'));

db.on('open', function () {
    let animalSchema = new Schema({ name: String, type: String });

    animalSchema.methods.findSimilarTypes = function (cb) {
        return this.model('animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
    };

    const animal = mongoose.model('animal', animalSchema, 'animal');
    let dog = new animal({ type: 'dog', name: 'doggy' });
    let cat = new animal({ type: 'cat', name: 'catty' });
    let yono = new animal({ type: 'dog', name: 'dini' });

    dog.findSimilarTypes(function (err, dogs) {
        console.log('dogs', dogs); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create new animals but dosen't save them to the database

```
let dog = new animal({ type: 'dog', name: 'doggy' }).save();
let cat = new animal({ type: 'cat', name: 'catty' }).save();
let yono = new animal({ type: 'dog', name: 'dini' }).save();
```

If you still get an empty array then there is some racing conditions which we will solve by using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and waiting for all the documents to get saved before we continue with our code

```
// Make our callback async function
db.on('open', async function () {
  let animalSchema = new Schema({ name: String, type: String });

  animalSchema.methods.findSimilarTypes = function (cb) {
    return this.model('animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
  };

  const animal = mongoose.model('animal', animalSchema, 'animal');
  let dog = new animal({ type: 'dog', name: 'doggy' });
  let cat = new animal({ type: 'cat', name: 'catty' });
  let yono = new animal({ type: 'dog', name: 'dini' });

  // Wait for our database to finish saving all of our animals
  await Promise.all([
    dog.save(),
    cat.save(),
    yono.save()
  ]);

  dog.findSimilarTypes(function (err, dogs) {
    console.log('dogs', dogs); 
  });
});
```